# How to remove the name of the window option in the application dock icon menu?

Tags: swift, xcode, menu, dock

How do I remove the window 'MyApp' from the application dock icon menu? I have a single window application so there is no need for this option.

I know I can hook into "`applicationDockMenu`" and return a menu as seen in the image with the 'Sample' option. However it won't allow me to remove the option above.

[image: Menu]